# android adjust view bounds after animation is finished

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a horizontal linear layout which has three children; a textview sandwiched between two buttons.

I have set the LinearLayout to be focusable, and the buttons to not be focusable, and added the following onFocusChangeListener to the LinearLayout:

```
        public void onFocusChange(final View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if(hasFocus)
            {
                v.startAnimation(_anims.Expand());
            }
            else
            {
                v.startAnimation(_anims.Unexpand());
            }
        }
```

The animations are as follows:

Expand:

```
<scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="1.2"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="200" />
```

and Unexpand:

```
<scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fromXScale="1.2"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.1"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="50" />
```

Everything appears to work OK, but unfortunately when the LinearLayout is expanded, the clickable area of the buttons appear to still appear to be where they would be in their 'unexpanded' state - ie at a scale of 0, so not matching up to where the buttons actually are on screen.

To attempt to combat this I thought of removing the fillEnabled and fillAfter tags, and adding an AnimationWatcher to the animation - setting the scale to the appropriate value when the Animation is finished. However this causes a slight 'flick' effect with the view going back to its original size before being expanded again once the animation is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because ViewAnimation does not change the actual position and size of your view. you have to set animation listeners and resize the view accordingly.

But there is an easy way if you are developing for >Honeycomb :
[ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

> quote from http://developer.android.com/
>
> ```
> ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(foo, "scale", 0f, 1f);
> anim.setDuration(1000);
> anim.start();
> ```

by using this you will not need to use animationlisteners.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything appears to work OK, but unfortunately when the LinearLayout is expanded, the clickable area of the buttons appear to be where they would be in their 'unexpanded' state...

This happens because you're using [View animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) here. That's an old animation system which was in Android since the beginning and one of its drawbacks is that it changes the *appearance* of the view (pixels on the screen), not its *actual* size/position. If you want to change not only appearance, but also `View`'s properties, use [Property animation framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) instead.